# Is there a way I can remove other components in the image except the beans using OpenCV python?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, python

I have been trying to remove every other component from the image except the beans. I have tried using edging and contour I couldn't get it right.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP67d.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What part of the image is the "beans"? Is it the circle or the dark region inside the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "beans" are the dark region, then here is one way in Python OpenCV.

```
 - Read the input
 - Threshold on the blue color
 - Apply morphology close to clean it up a little
 - Invert
 - Find the largest contour
 - Draw a white filled contour on a black background as a mask
 - Use the mask to make everything in the input black except the "beans"
 - Save the results
```

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("beans.jpg")

lower =(80,70,30)
upper = (220,220,180)

# create the mask and use it to change the colors
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# apply morphology
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# invert
morph = 255 - morph

# find largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw white filled contour on black background as mask
mask = np.zeros_like(thresh)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [big_contour], 0, 255, -1)

# apply mask to img
result = img.copy()
result[mask==0] = (0,0,0)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("beans_thresh2.png", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("beans_morph2.png", morph)
cv2.imwrite("beans_mask2.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("beans_result2.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Morphology cleaned image:

[image]

Mask Image:

[image]

Result Image:

[image]